# Python: Check count if data is there less than 15 min update as 1 else 0

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, frequency-analysis

```
timestamp,value
19/12/2017 12:00:00,12
19/12/2017 12:01:00,13
19/12/2017 12:05:00,15
19/12/2017 12:10:00,23
19/12/2017 12:11:00,46
19/12/2017 12:13:00,12
19/12/2017 12:14:59,34
19/12/2017 12:15:00,33
19/12/2017 12:16:00,33
19/12/2017 12:30:00,87
19/12/2017 12:50:00,44
19/12/2017 12:56:00,54
19/12/2017 1:16:00,54
19/12/2017 1:29:59,54
```

Logic :  <15min inclue 1 else 0

Above are the my dataset, Now i want set frequency for 15Min as if within 15Min data is there so in new column 
entry will be updated as 1. And if data is not the for the 15 min than entry will updated as 0.
Note: If wthin 15Min any one data also is there it will be one.

Condition will be;
If data is there within timestamp 12:00:00 to 12:14:59 than 1 else 0.
And if any missing data is there that also will be 0.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'] )
print (df)
mask=(df['timestamp'].dt.minute<15)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
```

Expected output:

```
2017-12-19 12:00:00     12    1    
2017-12-19 12:01:00     13    1  
2017-12-19 12:05:00     15    1  
2017-12-19 12:10:00     23    1  
2017-12-19 12:11:00     46    1
2017-12-19 12:13:00     12    1 
2017-12-19 12:14:59     34    1  
2017-12-19 12:15:00     33    1  
2017-12-19 12:16:00     33    1  
2017-12-19 12:30:00     87    1  
2017-12-19 12:50:00     44    1 
2017-12-19 12:56:00     54    1  
2017-12-19 01:00:00 to 2017-12-19 01:14:59 no data update as 0
2017-12-19 01:16:00     54    0    
2017-12-19 01:29:59     54    0
```

Requirement is;
I am checking for 15min frequency is data is not there or missing for 15 min than will make it as 0 and if data is there within 15min than will make it as 1.

Comment: what is expected output and what output you are getting with that code?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: `2017-12-19 12:30:00` to `2017-12-19 12:50:00` is that a special case or not required for some purpose?

Comment: yes because we are checking for 15min frequency is data is not there or missing for 15 min than will make it as 0 and if data is there within 15min than will make it as 1.

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: what needs to be updated please let me know?

Comment: check `df.shift()`

Comment: can u explain with code?

Answer (score 0):

This is code can obtain your desired output and help to obtain the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'] )
df['new'] = df['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0).abs().lt(60 * 15).astype(int) 
df = df.sort_values('timestamp', ascending=True)
plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['new'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: which column do you want to fill?